# Convert code from Windows Form Application to WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to convert code from a WFA (Windows Form Application) over to a WPF. However, i'm running into many difficulties. There is no .MaxLength. There is also no .Text as there is when using a Windows Form Application. How would i re-write the following code for WPF?

xbox is refering to a box on a chat window where the user types in text....

PS. The code below DOES work for WFA....

```
private void BoxChatAreaKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var xBox = (RichTextBox) sender;

    //setting a limit so the user cannot type more than 4000 characters at once
    xBox.MaxLength = 4000;
    if ((xBox.Text.Length > 1) && (e.KeyChar == (char) Keys.Enter))
    {
        WriteMessage(xBox);
    }
}

private static void WriteMessage(RichTextBox xBox)
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(_client.GetStream());
    String message = xBox.Text.TrimEnd('\n') + "|" + _font.Name;
    writer.WriteLine(message);
    writer.Flush();
    xBox.Text = null;
}
```

Comment: I'm not asking u to convert the entire thing, i just want to know the way around .Text and .MaxLength. Thanks for NOT helping...!

Comment: Then ask the specific question.   As for your general question (running into many difficulties) you are not going to be able to convert a forms application to a WPF without learning WPF.

Comment: Are you sending the entire text across the internet for every keypress?

Comment: I thought he did ask 2 specific questions that were quite reasonable.

Comment: @MikeKulls, i actually didn't think it through that well. But i guess perhaps with every key press up until enter i can append it to a string, right? And then send that string over...?

Comment: Most chat style apps just send a message at certain intervala to say "user is typing", then send the entire message when they push ok. You wouldn't need to append to a string, just grab the text from the RichTextBox. Btw, do you need a RTB? Could the standard textbox work for you? It has MaxLength and Text properties. You can change the font for the entire box which appears to be all you are doing for the RTB.

Comment: @MikeKulls, okay thanks :) everything is fixed up and working. Really appreciated your helpfulness!!! Happy holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
private void BoxChatAreaKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var xBox = (RichTextBox)sender;

    // Setting a limit so the user cannot type more than 4000 characters at once
    var textRange = new TextRange(xBox.Document.ContentStart, xBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    var textLen = textRange.Text.Trim();

    if (textLen.Length <= 4000)
    {
        if ((textLen.Length > 1) && (e.Key == Key.Enter))
        {
            WriteMessage(xBox);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of your application, it may not be straightforward directly converting from WinForm to WPF. To answer your two specific problems.

1) As you know, there's no `MaxLength` property on a RichTextBox in WPF. One way around this is to record the number of characters after the user has entered a character and check if it's greater than your limit. For example ([from here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/60426/Restricting-the-maximum-allowed-length-in-a-RichTe)):

```
private void xBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     TextRange tr = new TextRange(xBox.Document.ContentStart ,
                                    xBox.Document.ContentEnd);
     if (tr.Text.Length >= 4000 || e.Key == Key.Space || e.Key == Key.Enter)
     {
           e.Handled = true;
           return;
     }
}
```

2) Likewise, you can use the `TextRange` property to get the text within an RTB:

```
TextRange xBoxTR = new TextRange(xBox.Document.ContentStart, 
                                  xBox.Document.ContentEnd);

string xBoxText = xBoxTR.Text;
```